# PowerBI: Importing data from mixed folder files

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi, powerquery

I got a question related to the importing different files from the folder into Power Query (Power BI). When I say different, in my case are .xslx and .txt files. Actually just one text file but it is important to be inside report. Excel files are and will be always consistent as it is shown down in a first picture only with date as a dynamic part, but inside are consistently structured, so I just have to put it into folder and hit refresh into Power Query and magic..  that works fine, but I got also that .txt file which has completely different information but still connected to the report (because there is a field of date/time inside with additional information). My question is how or what is good approach to have all these files inside one or more queries?

[image]
[image]

As you can see on the second picture (from PQ editor) in the content part on the last position is .txt file, which I "isolated" when right click on it and "Add as a new query", and then I need to do editing and so on. Is there maybe another approach to solve this? One problem I discovered is when I change path of the file, all queries are refreshed but not this one with .txt - even though I changed path completely in the Advanced editor. Simply gives an error. Has anyone idea how to deal with different files from one folder, assuming that you need all the files from inside?

Comment: The best approach would be to separate the Excel and txt files into their own folder and load from there, particularly if they different in structure. Load from both folders then combine the query using merge/append etc when loaded into Power Query.

Comment: @Jonee Yes, that was how I did before. But I think I found a way, actually, it is very important from very start to define and to upload what will you do in the future, sometimes we cant predict, then it is hard time to include it in main report. 

Anyway, that was my issue, will have to look or to make from the beginning reports or to use from 2x folders as it was. 

Thx anyways for your suggest!

Comment: Why don't you just filter for the desired Extension?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want 2 folders, your approach for isolating the txt is appropriate. about refreshing issues: if you expanded the data by clicking combine, Excel must have created other queries and parameters ("Sample from....") you must change the path in those queries too.